# Dropbox: "Dropbox admin" (or similar) changed Dropbox contents

Tags: windows-10, security, dropbox, administrator

When I booted up the computer and logged in, I got a Windows 10 Notification saying something along the lines of "Dropbox admin added files". I am not sure about the exact wording and sadly, Windows 10 does not seem to keep a notifiaction history.

Looking into my Dropbox, I could see that a folder got copied from one of the sub-folders into my main folder. This action does not appear in the event history.

I have a private Dropbox account, so there is no account administrator who should have any access to my files.

What happend here? I cannot find anything about it using Google and I am concerned about the security and privacy of my files now.

Answer (score 1):

There has been no answer to this thread and I do not expect any answers at this point, but if somebody stumbles upon this, they might find this useful:

The issue might be related to this bug: https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/Missing-files-and-folders/deleted-folder-re-appeared-after-a-couple-of-years/m-p/203016/highlight/true#M8819